# MATLAB git by command window

Tags: git, matlab

I use [MATLABs git support](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/source-control.html) in the development of my code, often committing, pushing and all the standard source control stuff.

However, I have only used MATLABs user interface that basically works by right clicking on the folder and navigating through the menu until the right choice is found (see image below).

Is there a way to make MATLABs command window run `git` commands, instead of needing to navigate trough the menu each time?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the system command line escape `!` for git commands within MATLAB. Eg:

```
!git status
!git commit -am "Commit some stuff from MATLAB CLI"
!git push
```

You'll need to have Git installed on your system for this to work.

Comment: It is yes, although not specifically to use Git: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html

Another useful command is `system`. It allows return of status and result: `[status, result] = system('git status')`: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

Comment: I assume this, by accidet, solves my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271641/matlab-git-pull . Please, feel free to answer there also.

Comment: Oh yes, `system`. I like to avoid that, as any it will run *anything* (`rm -rf`). Calling `git` directly seems like a better idea.

Comment: Is there a way to have ML not freeze if you do a commit without -m and thus it opens vi?

Comment: Ay solution to push files to an external github repository ? I'm stuck with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370277/commiting-and-pushing-files-from-matlab-to-github-using-matlab-script

Answer (score 9):

I like to put the following function on my path:

```
function varargout = git(varargin)
% GIT Execute a git command.
%
% GIT <ARGS>, when executed in command style, executes the git command and
% displays the git outputs at the MATLAB console.
%
% STATUS = GIT(ARG1, ARG2,...), when executed in functional style, executes
% the git command and returns the output status STATUS.
%
% [STATUS, CMDOUT] = GIT(ARG1, ARG2,...), when executed in functional
% style, executes the git command and returns the output status STATUS and
% the git output CMDOUT.

% Check output arguments.
nargoutchk(0,2)

% Specify the location of the git executable.
gitexepath = 'C:\path\to\GIT-2.7.0\bin\git.exe';

% Construct the git command.
cmdstr = strjoin([gitexepath, varargin]);

% Execute the git command.
[status, cmdout] = system(cmdstr);

switch nargout
    case 0
        disp(cmdout)
    case 1
        varargout{1} = status;
    case 2
        varargout{1} = status;
        varargout{2} = cmdout;
end
```

You can then type git commands directly at the command line, without using `!` or `system`. But it has an additional advantage, in that you can also call the git command silently (no output to the command line) and with a status output. This makes it quite convenient if you're creating a script for an automated build, or release process.

Comment: This is very interesting! How do you call it? `git('commit',-'am','"mycomment"')`? Can you give some examples for posterity?

Comment: You can either call it in "command style" - i.e. you just type `git commit -m "mycomment"` at the MATLAB command line, or you can call it in "function style" - i.e. you use `[status, cmdout] = git('commit', '-m', '"mycomment"');`. I would use the first style if I'm just working interactively, but if I were building an automated build or release script I'd use the second.

Comment: As an example, I worked with a client recently to create a build and release script. The script called `git status` to ensure that local `dev` was up to date with the remote `dev`; called `git checkout -b` to make a release branch; updated the version number of the code in a `Contents.m` file; checked out `dev` and `master`, and called `git merge` to merge from the release branch; called `git push` to push `dev`, `master` and the release branch back to remote; and finally checked out `master` and called a makefile to build an artefact with MATLAB Compiler.

Comment: All of that was done using the "functional style", with the `status` output, to check that each step had succeeded. The functional style ensures that there is no output to the command line, so the build script can run silently.

Comment: Oh wow. I need to implement this for my software (TIGRE) to have some proper building and releasing approach

Comment: I just took a look at your TIGRE project - there's certainly things you could do modify your `Compile.m` into a more complete build and release script. With recent versions of MATLAB, you could also consider automatically packaging TIGRE into a toolbox (`.mltbx`) file. This would very likely help with usability. <ad> Let me know if you'd like some consulting to help out with that!</ad>

Comment: Just for completeness: There are at least two other git wrappers available on Mathworks File Exchange, i.e., [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/73895-git) and [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38600-git-matlab). However, I prefer @SamRoberts's solution for its versatility in terms of the optional output arguments. Why not publish it on File Exchange as well?

Answer (score 1):

From 23b there is a MATLAB Git API that does not require a Git installation: [gitrepo](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.git.gitrepository.html)/[gitclone](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gitclone.html).

Example usage:

```
>> repo = gitrepo(pwd);
>> add(repo,"newScript.m");
>> commit(repo,Files="newScript.m",Message="Commit new file");
```

To clone a repository:

```
>> repo = gitclone("https://github.com/myuser/myrepo");
```