# MATLAB git Pull

Tags: git, matlab

I am using MATLAB's git support, and interestingly there doesn't seem to be a "pull" option. There is "fetch" and "merge".

Is there a direct way of pulling from git in MATLAB?

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271061/matlab-git-by-command-window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271061/matlab-git-by-command-window/42271585?noredirect=1#comment71699450_42271585), this can be achieved using the shell escape `!`:

`!git pull`

Comment: Thank you! I will accept this as valid, but for other possible answers: I am still open to learn how can this be done without calling another program (`!git`)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd do this the way tuna_fish has suggested; it's neat.

However, as you're looking to do it with the integration, I'll point out that, as the [git pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) says, a `git pull` is just a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. So you could use those two features sequentially.