# Why does Matlab (or git?) not recognize wincred

Tags: git, matlab, github

I am working with `RStudio` and set up `wincred` correcly. No I would like to make matlab aware of wincred. Any ideas? I found [this](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/263934-every-time-i-push-to-the-remote-github-repository-i-have-to-re-input-my-username-and-password-is-t) useful link but do not understand why this does not work for matlab: I already have a key and access to github is working! Please let me know, if you need further information.

I have the following directories:

- C:/Test_Mathlab ...... Here is my code
- C:/Users/user/.ssh ... Here is my ssh key (which is working for RStudio)

**Those `git` settings** might be useful:

```
$ git config --list --show-origin
...
file:"C:\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   credential.helper=manager
file:C:/Users/sqc/.gitconfig    user.name=my name
file:C:/Users/sqc/.gitconfig    user.email=my.name@example.com
file:C:/Users/sqc/.gitconfig    credential.helper=wincred
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://github.com/path2/Test_Matlab
file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
...
```

(Adding a line

```
file:.git/config        credential.helper=wincred
```

does not help)

**PS:** I made it somehow to work with RStudio, but my knowledge on what is going on is really poor;-)

Comment: MATLAB does not access that info, but you can always call `git` by command [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271061/matlab-git-by-command-window). In that case, your credentials are not asked. I think MATLAB is just meh for this things.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Have you tried the procedure in the link? I already did that (I use `https://github.com/...` instead `git@github.com:username/...` because I had trouble with git if I remember correctly) and I thought `matlab` just implemented a wrapper around git. Thus my remark that `git` might not find the correct settings.

Comment: No idea. I set up my git via Git Bash, and when that works, if I push with MATLAB, it ask for credential, but if I push with `!git push` in the command, then it does not. Can't help more that that

Comment: @AnderBiguri You are right, thanks! Weird. I let you know if I understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after a discussion with the Matlab support: According to the support, Matlab uses jGit, which is a bit different. Thus, the "Matlab-push" command does not know anything about the credential helper which is set on the system level (see `file:"C:\\Git...`).

**The solution is as follows:**

Use an `ssh key` and not a credential helper. For github, this is discussed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/). Furthermore, I did a mistake in [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) step: I forgot to copy the key to my Github account.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB release R2021a if a credential helper is setup and defined in your Git config it will be used to store and retrieve your credentials ([Set Up Git Source Control](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-git-source-control.html))

Comment: If you add the steps which you used, this might become a really good answer. (links can break ;-) and without the link you are lost.)