# How can I use third-party/command line git with MATLAB open?

Tags: windows, git, matlab

Using the command line or a third-party git manager, I can execute basic `git` commands like `commit`, `reset` and `stash` with MATLAB open, presumably because I'm working solely on my local branch. As soon as I want to use `git checkout somebranch` I get the error:

`fatal: cannot create directory at [dir]: Permission denied`

What's worse is that my current working directory (on the old branch) now has unstaged changes from the branch I wanted to checkout. Other programs simply reload the files from the newly checked out branch. I've tried finding a way to change how MATLAB locks files but to no avail.

MATLAB R2017b
Windows 10 Pro

**More Info**

The file structure in my git directory is different between the two branches. I think the issue arises from the fact that a deleted sub-directory was in MATLAB's "set path" list.

Comment: Are you calling git from a separate software,or [from MATLAB itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271061/matlab-git-by-command-window)?

Comment: Interesting. There is a difference if the files that staged while commiting are open in the editor or not?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm trying to call git from a separate software (GitHub/Sourcetree) or from Git Shell. I can use MATLAB's built-in git manager without an issue but I would rather not. I saw the link about using git commands in the command window, but I need to change some system variable first... maybe it's the best option.

Comment: @Adiel The issue persists after closing all the files in my editor.

Comment: Note that the file structure in my git directory is different between the two branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend

- using a separate git (from the [latest Git for Windows and a simplified path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309))
- using a separate working tree (meaning a separate folder) with [git worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309).

Second, double-check any locking issue with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to be working, but I had previously merged the branch I was having issues with (the one with a different file structure), so I can't test directly. I think the issue was due to MATLAB having a folder in its "set path" list that was changed between the two branches. I assume a separate working tree would fix this (although I would need to setup new paths for MATLAB). I've accepted your answer.