# Commiting and pushing files from MATLAB to Github using MATLAB script

Tags: git, matlab

I'd like to push a excel file to my github repository(external) that's generated after running a MATLAB script.
I was able to run these below MATLAB commands but not sure how to connect and push to an external github repository

```
[~, userNameOutput] = system('git config --global user.name');
[~, branchNameOutput] = system('git name-rev --name-only HEAD');
[~, gitCommitSHA] = system('git rev-parse HEAD');
```

I'm looking something like this [Ocktokit library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/octokit) where I can provide auth and commit and push the files using git commands

Comment: Might make your Googling simpler to ignore the fact you're using MATLAB here, none of that code is native MATLAB, you're just invoking system calls which would be the same from any terminal

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271061/matlab-git-by-command-window

Comment: @Wolfie Yes you are right , but I'm running these commands in my MATLAB editor and I want to push the files to an external github repository from MATLAB

Comment: @AnderBiguri The example that's shown in the question is pushing the files in the same repository, but my requirement is to push to another external repository, which is not opened in the current MATLAB window

Comment: @forgottofly the answers in that question are for "how to do anything you can do in git, in matlab". Is your question then completely unrelated to MATLAB, and are you asking how to do that in git? You can not push from repository A to repository B if they don't have the same history, it breaks the entire point of git.